# Typescript build dependant on the target

Tags: javascript, import, build, package

Given a javascript module/package, which has a dependency/import in index.js that must be different depending on the target (web/node), what can be done to create 2 builds or a build that requires an import dynamically in a specific environment?

```
import leveldown from "leveldown" // fails in browser
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic imports (browser support: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import) (node support >10.0)

```
let DB_ADAPTER;
if (!!window) {
    DB_ADAPTER = Promise.resolve("empty")
} else {
    DB_ADAPTER = import("leveldown")
}
```